# Can typedef used for vector in general?

Tags: c++, typedef

In general, we can do

```
typedef std::vector<int> container1;
typedef std::vector<char> container2;
```

But it looks like we can't do something like.

```
typedef vector container;
container<int> ins;
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? What I can think of is using macro.

Comment: I think this is called a higher kinded type (specifically `* -> *`)

Comment: Declarations containing the decl-speciﬁer typedef declare identiﬁers that can be used later for naming fundamental (3.9.1) or compound (3.9.2) types. vector is not a complete type but template class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[C++11 aliases allows this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;   
Vec<int> v;   // same as std::vector<int> v;
```

[also see this](https://blogs.oracle.com/pcarlini/entry/template_aliases)

And in a similar fashion, you can rewrite the typedefs in C++11, as:

```
using container1 = std::vector<int>;
using container2 = std::vector<char>;
```

These are exactly  same as the typedefs in your question.

Comment: Outside of C++, you can do `template<typename T> struct container { typedef std::vector<T> type; };` (and replace the `std::vector` with whatever container if you choose), and use `typename container<T>::type`.  It sucks.

Comment: @perreal: I edited your answer. Hope that is fine with you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it generates more questions for me. What is the difference between typedef and using? when should I use them? ...:)

Comment: @perreal It looks like it duplicated now. Should I do something on my original question post or I can just leave it along?

Comment: just leave it, no objections so far